# Exchange 2010 - Outlook 2010: Does backing up email to local PST remove emails from server?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010

We're going to be migrating our Exchange environment to Office 365 but I'd like to create local backups of each mailbox before doing the final migration.

If I create a .PST backup of a mailbox will that remove those emails from our Exchange server?

It has been a long time since I did anything with .PSTs and I just don't remember. However, I want to ensure that by backing up these emails to PST it will not remove them from our server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably not, I believe it just copies them. Try it with just a few to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't and you could easily copy mails back if you for some reason would lose Mail on the Server.

Its sort of a private Copy (hence the name "Personal Storage Table") of your Mails. Thats why a lot of Server Admins disable this feature, to make sure a Client cannot copy his Mail elsewhere.